# Файл с каким именем нужно создать, чтобы отобразить запись нового типа?

Tags: wordpress

Создаю новый тип записей `projects`

```html
function projects_cp() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Проекты', 'Post Type General Name', 'projects' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Проекты', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'projects' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Проекты', 'projects' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Родительский:', 'projects' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'Все записи', 'projects' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'Просмотреть', 'projects' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Добавить новый Проект', 'projects' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Добавить новую', 'projects' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Редактировать запись', 'projects' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Обновить запись', 'projects' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Найти запись', 'projects' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Не найдено', 'projects' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Не найдено в корзине', 'projects' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array('title', 'editor','thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'projects_tax' ), // Категории, которые мы создадим ниже
        'public'              => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
    );

    register_post_type( 'projects', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'projects_cp', 0 ); // инициализируем
```

Вывожу записи нового типа на страницу.
Ссылка выведена с помощью `the_permalink`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ведет данная ссылка на `index`. Wordpress ищет файл с определенным именем и не находя его, переходит на страницу `index.php` так вот какое имя должно быть у файла, чтобы там отображать записи? Для стандартных записей (`post`) это `single.php` а для добавленных записей как должен называться файл?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ссылка выводится с помощью the_permalink(). Об иерархии шаблонов WordPress можно почитать тут: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Да, я исправил, (не то скопировал)

Comment: Я так и понял, иначе бы в строке браузера на второй картинке не было правильного URL. Читайте иерархию.

Comment: В add_action 0 - это перебор. Жёстко) опустите этот аргумент, пусть будет 10 по умолчанию

Comment: Что-то не так. Прочитал про иерархию, спасибо! Действительно нужная информация.
Проблема оказалась в следующем: я создал файл single-projects.php, single-project.php. Все равно переходит на index.php хотя, согласно иерархии должен был как минимум на single.php перейти. Что может быть не так?

Comment: Тема своя небось, с нуля?))

Comment: И еще: permalinks сохраняли в админке после создания кастомного типа поста?

Comment: В точку!))
Насчет permalinks  не понял. У меня были проекты в виде записей обычных. Попросили сделать дополнительный тип записей для проектов, чтобы была возможность если что добавлять обычные записи.
Я в цикле, где выводятся записи просто поставил $args = array('post_type'   => 'projects', );
Отобразилось корректно.
Но не переходит корректно на single-projects.php и т.д.

Comment: Если тема своя - с вероятностью 99% косяк там. Смотрите, как работает стандартная тема, и повторяйте. Не видя ваших файлов советовать сложно.  Насколько я помню, после создания нового типа постов один раз надо сохранить структуру постоянных ссылок в Настройки - > Постоянные ссылки.

Comment: ААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААБаааалдеть!!!!!! Действительно косяк в постоянных ссылках!!! Я поставил другой тип ссылок, сохранил, поставил старый тип ссылок, сохранил и все заработало!!!!
2,5 часа на то, чтобы узнать о такой магии wp!
Сделай что-ли это ответом, я отмечу. Спасибо, в жизни бы никогда не догадался

Comment: можно было, ничего не меняя, просто нажать на кнопку Сохранить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Об иерархии шаблонов WordPress можно почитать в [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).

И после создания кастомного типа постов надо один раз пересохранить структуру постоянных ссылок в Настройки->Постоянные ссылки.